# How do I force a CFFI-defined foreign library to use a specific version of a shared library?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf, cffi

I'm using CL-SQLITE, a Common Lisp wrapper for SQLite3 written using CFFI (the Common Foreign-Function Interface). My preferred C runtime is UCRT64 as distributed with MSYS. Unfortunately, MSYS uses its own naming conventions for DLLs, so the default filenames that CFFI searches for will not be found. I want to tell CL-SQLITE to load my special DLL instead of searching for the default option. I do not want to modify CL-SQLITE code since that would create a maintenance burden. I also do not want to do "the easy thing" and copy the DLL to my project directory, renaming it as needed; when I incorporate other shared libraries into my project, these copy operations will become a problem.

I'm also using ASDF and DEPLOY, so if those tools provide a solution, then I can work with that.

I tried to use DEPLOY's define-library to point to my local DLL, but define-library depends on successfully loading the CFFI system. CL-SQLITE won't successfully QL:QUICKLOAD because the DLL it's looking for has a different name than the one I have.

I also tried adding a directory to cffi:*foreign-library-directories*. This did not solve the problem because the *file name* is different; the directory name is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread the question at first, thinking that OP was using CLSQL instead of CL-SQLITE. I have left the original answer below. Both answers are fundamentally the same, but CLSQL provides additional means to configure the library load path.

The system is looking for either `sqlite3.dll` or `libsqlite3.dll`, but this file is named `libsqlite3-0.dll` in my MSYS2 installation, where it can be found in `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\`. You can create a soft link to the installed library file named `sqlite3.dll` from the MSYS2 UCRT64 command prompt:

```
$ cd /c/msys64/ucrt64/bin/
$ ln -s libsqlite3-0.dll sqlite3.dll
```

The [CL-SQLITE installation instructions](https://cl-sqlite.common-lisp.dev/#installation) say that the Windows PATH environment variable needs to contain a path to the directory containing `sqlite3.dll`, so add that in the usual way, e.g., from the Windows Control Panel.

After these two steps CL-SQLITE should load as expected.

Setting the Windows PATH variable will also allow CLSQL to find `sqlite3.dll`, but CLSQL provides an alternative way to set the load path which is described in my original answer below.

#### Original Answer:

I had the same problem and had to do two things to solve it.

In my installation of MSYS2 the `sqlite3` library was named `libsqlite3-0.dll`. From a UCRT64 terminal window I created a soft link named `sqlite3.dll` in that directory:

```
$ cd /c/msys64/ucrt64/bin/
$ ln -s libsqlite3-0.dll sqlite3.dll
```

Then I had to add a search path so that CLSQL could find the library code. You can do `CL-USER> (clsql:push-library-path #P"C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/")` after loading CLSQL with Quicklisp, or you can create an initialization file. This isn't very well documented: there is a [brief mention in the CLSQL docs](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/UNOFFICIAL/docs/clsql/doc/appendix.html), and some more information can be gleaned from searching the [CLSQL change log](https://clsql.kpe.io/changelog.html) for clsql-init. It appears that you can add a file named `clsql-init.lisp` under `/etc/` on *nix systems, or under `c:\etc\clsql-init.lisp` on Windows systems, or under `~/.clsql-init.lisp` on either type of system. Note that this last variation is a dot file.

I added `.clsql-init.lisp` to my home directory:

```lisp
;;; Add library path for sqlite3.
(clsql:push-library-path #P"C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/")
```

After making these two changes everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! I marked your answer as the accepted one.